# error code 3 while trying to upload shapefile to google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to upload a shapefile as a zip in Google Earth engine

[image]

The original zip is [here](https://github.com/derek-corcoran-barrios/PupulationCoast/blob/master/Coastal.zip) if you need to try it. The error I get is the following one

```
Asset name: projects/earthengine-legacy/assets/users/derek_corcoran/Coastal
ID: ZU2VC3KLXWKN453JYYLVMKRS
Phase: Failed
Runtime: 19s (started 2022-11-15 19:18:40 +0100)
Attempted 1 time
Error: Projection exception. Ensure the projection is specified correctly and the coordinates are within its valid area. Detailed error: Unable to transform edge (8862777.916769, 7856465.827724 to 8862776.700196, 7856466.166777) from PROJCS["unknown", GEOGCS["GCS_unknown", DATUM["D_WGS_1984", SPHEROID["WGS_1984", 6378137.0, 298.257223563]], PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], AXIS["Longitude", EAST], AXIS["Latitude", NORTH]], PROJECTION["Mollweide"], PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0], PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], UNIT["m", 1.0], AXIS["x", EAST], AXIS["y", NORTH]] PLANAR to EPSG:4326.. (Error code: 3)
```

It seems that the correction is the issue, but the chosen projection is the one I could use in order to get that polygon to work, the source code on building that polygon is [here](https://github.com/derek-corcoran-barrios/PupulationCoast) in this repo

I am not sure what is wrong, I am very new using google earth engine

Answer (score 0):

I saw that the .prj file in your shape .zip contains no information on the projection: `PROJCS["unknown",GEOGCS["GCS_unknown"...`

In the github repo you linked a Mollweide projection is specified here:  `terra::project("+proj=moll")`

Maybe exchange `+proj=moll` for a EPSG:4326 projection to produce the shapes: `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs`